# git log show file blob id

Tags: python, git

Having the command

`git --no-pager log -m --first-parent --no-renames --reverse --name-status --pretty=oneline --full-index`

is there any way to also get the blob hash for each file at that particular commit, next to the "name status"?

The command is used in a deployment pipeline for some huge repositories, so whatever the solution, I aim at keeping it fast, meaning: not spawning new processes.

If not possible, an acceptable approach would be to use a python library / binding. If you think that's the best approach, then please point to some key API calls which I'd need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remove `--name-status` and add `--raw`, I see a format where each individual blob has a `before...  after...` hash.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up with `git --no-pager log -m --first-parent --no-renames --reverse --no-abbrev --raw --pretty=oneline --full-index`

Comment: Update: `git --no-pager log -m --first-parent --no-renames --decorate=full --reverse --no-abbrev --raw --pretty=oneline --full-index`